# How to properly structure relationship from pre-established choices (or new if not exists) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a quick and simple question of thinking the database. I have a User model and a Hotel model.

Each user has a hotel and can select one of those from the hotels table OR add hotel name and address if his hotel is not found on the table. What is the best way to do that? I don't want users to be able to create hotels. So what I thought was:

1- Users table
-- User.hotel-name
-- User.hotel-address

2- Hotels table
-- Hotel.name
-- Hotel.address

If the user selects an existing hotel, it would "copy" the info from this hotel. But that does not seem correct. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that and normalizing de database is create another table HotelUsers including the hotels created by Users.

1. You check if hotel exist in HOTEL table.
2. Next check if hotel exists in HOTELUSERS with de id of user.
3. create new HOTELUSER copy of Hotel or new by User

HOTELUSERS
userId
name
address

ANOTHER WAY

You also can have a relationship many to many in USERS <-> HOTEL and store one parameter on HOTEL table for knowing when hotel is create by user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what would be the best way to get users hotel? Creating a helper?

Comment: From UserController you can access to HotelUsers and Hotel is the best way, you don't need use the helper, the helper is used for the views, the aim of helpers is free code of the views and put it on helpers to avoid a 'full code view'

Comment: This is great if each user can have multiple hotels, but I think OP is asking for only one hotel per user, in which case a linking table is superfluous

Comment: The OP wants a copy of hotels

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as though each user belongs to a hotel (in the database relational way anyway), so you would have a user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hotel
  ...
end
```

And a hotel model:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  ...
end
```

That means that the the user table would have a hotelId column, where you would store the hotel it relates to.
Where the user is associated with a hotel in the code, something like:

```
... #sanitize name & address from params
user.hotel = Hotel.first_or_create(name: name, address: address)
....
```

This would set the users hotel to either one that already exists with that name and address or creates a new one

Comment: Thank you @Yule, but the point here is that I don't want users to create hotels that would be shared with other users. They'd have a list of hotels, if none found, they could add one just for them.

Comment: I think you still should have two separate tables in the database, it's storing information about two separate entities. Perhaps have a boolean attribute on hotel, which is 'user_created' and not include these in the drop down?

Comment: I think that is the best approach. I will go with two different tables and then create a method to determine which object is returned when I go for User.determinehotel or something like that. Thank you!

Comment: @Guido curious, if you're going with this approach, why accept another answer?

Comment: Fair enough, up to you. However, the other answer actually suggested 3 tables (which is great for a many to many relationship).